# Replicate Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES in Python 2.7

Tags: java, python-2.7, encryption, md5, des

If it's not immediately obvious, let me start by saying I am not a crypto person.

I have been tasked with replicating the behavior of Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES (MD5 digest with DES encryption) in Python 2.7.

I do have access to Python's cryptography toolkit PyCrypto.

Here is the Java code whose behavior I am trying to replicate:

```
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class EncryptInJava
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String encryptionPassword = "q1w2e3r4t5y6";
      byte[] salt = { -128, 64, -32, 16, -8, 4, -2, 1 };
      int iterations = 50;

      try
      {
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(encryptionPassword.toCharArray(), salt, iterations);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations);

        Cipher encoder = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        encoder.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

        String str_to_encrypt = "MyP455w0rd";
        byte[] enc = encoder.doFinal(str_to_encrypt.getBytes("UTF8"));

        System.out.println("encrypted = " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(enc));
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

For the given values, it outputs the following:

```
encrypted = Icy6sAP7adLgRoXNYe9N8A==
```

Here's my ham-handed attempt to port the above to Python, `encrypt_in_python.py`:

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

_password = 'q1w2e3r4t5y6'
_salt = '\x80\x40\xe0\x10\xf8\x04\xfe\x01'
_iterations = 50
plaintext_to_encrypt = 'MyP455w0rd'

if "__main__" == __name__:

    """Mimic Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm to produce a DES key"""
    hasher = MD5.new()
    hasher.update(_password)
    hasher.update(_salt)
    result = hasher.digest()

    for i in range(1, _iterations):
        hasher = MD5.new()
        hasher.update(result)
        result = hasher.digest()

    key = result[:8]

    encoder = DES.new(key)
    encrypted = encoder.encrypt(plaintext_to_encrypt + ' ' * (8 - (len(plaintext_to_encrypt) % 8)))
    print encrypted.encode('base64')
```

It outputs a completely different string.

Is it possible to port the Java implementation to a Python implementation with standard Python libraries?

Apparently the Python implementation requires that the plaintext that I encrypt be a multiple of eight characters, and I'm not even sure exactly how to pad my plaintext input to meet that condition.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See [rfc 2898](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898), specifically [section 6.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898#section-6.1). You need to use DES in CBC mode with the key being the first 8 bytes and the IV being the second 8 bytes of your hash result.

Comment: This is a bad password derivation method and shouldn't be used. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration (the salt needs to be saved with the hash). Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Comment: Also see [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to GregS's comment, I was able to sort this conversion out!

For future reference, this Python code mimics the behavior of the Java code above:

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

_password = 'q1w2e3r4t5y6'
_salt = '\x80\x40\xe0\x10\xf8\x04\xfe\x01'
_iterations = 50
plaintext_to_encrypt = 'MyP455w0rd'

# Pad plaintext per RFC 2898 Section 6.1
padding = 8 - len(plaintext_to_encrypt) % 8
plaintext_to_encrypt += chr(padding) * padding

if "__main__" == __name__:

    """Mimic Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm to produce a DES key"""
    hasher = MD5.new()
    hasher.update(_password)
    hasher.update(_salt)
    result = hasher.digest()

    for i in range(1, _iterations):
        hasher = MD5.new()
        hasher.update(result)
        result = hasher.digest()

    encoder = DES.new(result[:8], DES.MODE_CBC, result[8:16])
    encrypted = encoder.encrypt(plaintext_to_encrypt)

    print encrypted.encode('base64')
```

This Python code outputs the following in Python 2.7:

```
Icy6sAP7adLgRoXNYe9N8A==
```

Thanks again to GregS for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Actually just in case someone (like me) is wondering how was \xe0 calculated as the hex for -32, the way you do it is as follows:
so you find the hex of 31, which is 0x1f and subtract it from 0xff. 
So 0xff - 0x1f = 0xe0. 
So that's how you derive the hexadecimal equivalents of negative integers. For an explanation of the same (why and how) Google for number systems and negative number representations in different number systems.

Answer (score 3):

For Python 3.6, I tested with following code and it works with a little change from above:

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
import base64
import re

_password = b'q1w2e3r4t5y6'
_salt = b'\x80\x40\xe0\x10\xf8\x04\xfe\x01'

_iterations = 50

plaintext_to_encrypt = 'MyP455w0rd'

# Pad plaintext per RFC 2898 Section 6.1
padding = 8 - len(plaintext_to_encrypt) % 8
plaintext_to_encrypt += chr(padding) * padding

if "__main__" == __name__:

    """Mimic Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm to produce a DES key"""
    hasher = MD5.new()
    hasher.update(_password)
    hasher.update(_salt)
    result = hasher.digest()

    for i in range(1, _iterations):
        hasher = MD5.new()
        hasher.update(result)
        result = hasher.digest()

    encoder = DES.new(result[:8], DES.MODE_CBC, result[8:16])
    encrypted = encoder.encrypt(plaintext_to_encrypt)

    print (str(base64.b64encode(encrypted),'utf-8'))

    decoder = DES.new(result[:8], DES.MODE_CBC, result[8:])
    d = str(decoder.decrypt(encrypted),'utf-8')
    print (re.sub(r'[\x01-\x08]','',d))
```

Output:

> Icy6sAP7adLgRoXNYe9N8A==
>
> MyP455w0rd

Answer (score 0):

I found one from [here](https://github.com/binsgit/PBEWithMD5AndDES)

```
import base64
import hashlib
import re
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
def get_derived_key(password, salt, count):
    key = password + salt
    for i in range(count):
        m = hashlib.md5(key)
        key = m.digest()
    return (key[:8], key[8:])
def decrypt(msg, password):
    msg_bytes = base64.b64decode(msg)
    salt = '\xA9\x9B\xC8\x32\x56\x35\xE3\x03'
    enc_text = msg_bytes
    (dk, iv) = get_derived_key(password, salt, 2)
    crypter = DES.new(dk, DES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    text = crypter.decrypt(enc_text)
    return re.sub(r'[\x01-\x08]','',text)
def encrypt(msg, password):
    salt = '\xA9\x9B\xC8\x32\x56\x35\xE3\x03'
    pad_num = 8 - (len(msg) % 8)
    for i in range(pad_num):
        msg += chr(pad_num)
    (dk, iv) = get_derived_key(password, salt, 2)
    crypter = DES.new(dk, DES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    enc_text = crypter.encrypt(msg)
    return base64.b64encode(enc_text)
def main():
    msg = "hello"
    passwd = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    encrypted_msg = encrypt(msg, passwd)
    print encrypted_msg
    plain_msg = decrypt(encrypted_msg, passwd)
    print plain_msg
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the newer Cryptodome library with Python 3, you'll need to also encode your plaintext_to_encrypt to 'latin-1', as is shown below.

```
from Cryptodome.Hash import MD5
from Cryptodome.Cipher import DES
import base64
import re

_password = b'q1w2e3r4t5y6'
_salt = b'\x80\x40\xe0\x10\xf8\x04\xfe\x01'

_iterations = 50

plaintext_to_encrypt = 'MyP455w0rd'

# Pad plaintext per RFC 2898 Section 6.1
padding = 8 - len(plaintext_to_encrypt) % 8
plaintext_to_encrypt += chr(padding) * padding

if "__main__" == __name__:

    """Mimic Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm to produce a DES key"""
    hasher = MD5.new()
    hasher.update(_password)
    hasher.update(_salt)
    result = hasher.digest()

    for i in range(1, _iterations):
        hasher = MD5.new()
        hasher.update(result)
        result = hasher.digest()

    encoder = DES.new(result[:8], DES.MODE_CBC, result[8:16])
    encrypted = encoder.encrypt(plaintext_to_encrypt.encode('latin-1'))  #encoded plaintext

    print (str(base64.b64encode(encrypted),'utf-8'))

    decoder = DES.new(result[:8], DES.MODE_CBC, result[8:])
    d = str(decoder.decrypt(encrypted),'utf-8')
    print (re.sub(r'[\x01-\x08]','',d))
```